# Long running methods in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application in that on form submit,

```
1. I have a long running 2 methods(each method process approx 15 min)

2. First method returns a boolean.

3. Second method return class object.
```

Using those class object will process database entry.

My question here is,

```
1. How to acheive this without making UI hangs for longer duration?

2. Since there will be numerous form submit, 
can thread concept be handy by making it as background thread? 
or anything else like backgroundworker, async/await, windows service with queues like msmq or rabbitmq or someother new concepts?

3. If any, can you explain to achieve it?

4. Last question is, I need to display a progress bar(in jquery) during long running methods,
    On first method return i should send a status like first method completed.
    On second method return i should send a status like second method completed.

5. How could i pass those method return value to jquery?
```

If any answers will be much appreciated.

-Prasanth

Comment: you cant expect the user to keep the tab open for 30 mins..its better to just let the user submit the form..take the user to next page showing status that the process will take arnd 30 minutes.. when the first method is over, flag this somewhere (in the db, cache whatever), so that if the user goes to the page for status, he can know that 50% of the work is done

Comment: Answer for 1. 2. and 3.- **Check out Hangfire.io - background processing of long running tasks**

4.    **Check out SignalR - to push data from server to client or go for short/long polling (not recommended though) **

Comment: You can try Windows Service as background worker; and polling or SignalR for task completed event.